# A Function Returns a List with one Value. How to assign it?

Tags: python, coding-style, iterable-unpacking

[`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html#numpy.correlate) returns an array of length 1 for arguments of equal length. What is the best way to assign that one value, but not the array?

- `[result] = numpy.correlate([1], [1])`
- `result, = numpy.correlate([1], [1])`
- `result = numpy.correlate([1], [1])[0]`

If I understand [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) in Python 3.5 correctly, this would additionally allow:

- `result = *numpy.correlate([1], [1])`

Is there a canonical correct way of writing this?

Comment: Can you define "best"?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik "best", as in "most pythonic", preferably without any performance penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form:

```
result = numpy.correlate([1], [1])[0]
```

is more similar to other languages, so, in my opinion, it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: I tend to agree; OTOH, the other 2 forms throw a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` exception if the function happens to return a list of more than one element, which may be useful.

Comment: I just checked: this is about 25% faster than the other two options.